# real Device orientation even on locked UIView

Tags: objective-c, device-orientation

How can I find out the real iOS-Device orientation (not UIView orientation) even on a locked UIView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might help you.

```
UIDeviceOrientation currentDeviceOrientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];
```